# How to define and test a macro for a string value?

Tags: c++, c

If I define macro a number and use it in if conditions, it works the way I want. But not when I define it as a string (I don't know for sure if its string):

```
#define X surjit

#if(X == prachee)
#error "you're wrong"
#elif(X == manish)
#error "you're wrong again"
#elif(X == surjit)
#error "now you got it"
#endif
```

I was expecting it to print `now you got it`. But it prints `you're wrong`.
I even tried defining it as string explicitly as

```
#define X "surjit"
```

But that throws en error as follows

```
error: token ""surjit"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

Comment: All of `surjit`, `prachee` and `manish` are macro names. None are defined. For purposes of arithmetic comparisons, they are taken to have a value of 0. That's why, say, `#if (surjit == prachee)` condition holds: it's equivalent to `if (0 == 0)`. For the second question: `#if ("surjit" == prachee)` is syntactically invalid, and doesn't make mush sense. Preprocessor cannot do string comparison; write actual C or C++ code for that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik totally got it.. thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't.

The preprocessor only understands integer expressions in `#if`. That's why string literals such as `"surjit"` cause an error.

Undefined identifiers are replaced by `0` for evaluation in `#if`/`#elif`, which is why `surjit == prachee` becomes `0 == 0` and evaluates as true.

One possible workaround is to give those names distinct integer values:

```
#define prachee 1
#define manish 2
#define surjit 3
```